# How to insert double quotes inside mongo db string datatype for storing blog posts?

Tags: python

I have created a flask application that stores blog posts inside mongodb. But Now I face a problem when I attempt to show images like `<img src="/static/img/blog.jpg">`inside those posts. Because those double quotes create problem in mongo db. When it appears in html it looks something like this `&lt;img src = &#34;/static/img/blog.jpg&#34;&gt;`

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are passing double quotes in a string you would need to escape the characters.

```
"<Img src=\"url\">"
```

Also in jinja if you want to render the html code you need to use `|safe`